# How to get all users email from this API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am using this API and trying to get all of the user's emails. I tried looping the result, but it just returns the first result looped to the number of users.

Below is my current code.

```
def get_user():

    url = 'https://api.pagerduty.com/users'
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
        'Authorization': 'Token token={token}'.format(token=API_KEY)
    }

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    result = []
    emails = r.json()['users'][0]['email']
    for email in emails:
        if r.status_code == 200:
            result.append(emails)
    return result
```

I am currently returning the result in an appended list, which is not working, so how do I get the email of each user, not just the first one?

Comment: Should it be `result.append(email)` .... not `emails`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I just tried that and it returns the first letter for each user's email.

Comment: It looks like you should be looping over the users and for each user getting their email.  What does the full response object look like?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh the full response is similar to what's here: https://api-reference.pagerduty.com/#!/Users/get_users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the `users` object and get the `email` from each user.  Currently, you are only getting the email for user 0.

```
if r.status_code == 200:
    result = [user['email'] for user in r.json()['users']]
else:
    # raise some error, set result = [], or some other indication of failure
```